# I'd like to find a decimal number in url with notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'd like to find a string in url with notepad++ regular expression. Unfortunately I can't.

> http://www.example.com/profile/mera-handelsgesellschaft-mbh-182055?category_id=154331

What I want to have is `182055`

I will only find it. Not change.

My last try was `([^\-|^\=])(\d+)([^\?])`

How can I find it

Comment: try `\d+(?=\?)` https://regex101.com/r/wW7eH8/1

Comment: that is for me really magic. could you explain a little bit please

Comment: I explain in my answer..

Answer (score 0):

try this regex please:

```
\d+(?=\?)
```

`\d` look for a digits

`\d+` look for one or more digits

`(?=\?)` is a Positive Lookahead. This means that select one or more digits that there is a `?` character after them.

from regex101:

> ```
> \d+ match a digit [0-9]
>     Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
> (?=\?) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
>     \? matches the character ? literally
> ```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wW7eH8/1)**